# Use of fscanf with comma separated values in Matlab

Tags: matlab, file-io, serial-port, scanf

Over serial, I am getting values like

23,2004,5000 
24,5005,5060 
25,6789,8907

How do I separate these into three columns?

For one column, e.g:

25 
24 
26

I can just do

```
clc;clear all;close all;
arduino=serial('COM4','BaudRate',9600);
fopen(arduino);
tic;
i=0;
while toc<120;
    i = i+1;
    time(i)= toc;
    v(i)=fscanf(arduino,'%d');
    plot(time,v,'r');
    pause(.10);
end
fclose(arduino)
```

and  store all data in v. How to adapt this code for 3 columns?

Comment: One way would be to use `strtok` and `str2num`: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strtok.html

Answer (score 1):

I dont have anything connected to serial port, so I cant test this, but inside the loop try:

```
str = fgetl(arduino);
num = textscan(str, '%f', 'Delimiter',','); num = num{1};
%# `num` should be a 3x1 vector of numbers
```

First read a line of text from device using [serial.fgetl](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/serial.fgetl.html), then parse the string using `textscan` or any other similar string function.

Comment: or maybe just: `fscanf(arduino, '%d,%d,%d')`

Answer (score -1):

What about this:

```
 A = cell2mat(textscan(arduino,'%d,%d,%d'))
```

Comment: `arduino` is a `serial` object, I dont think the class have a `textscan` method. You might have to read the whole line first, then use `textscan` on the string